# Persist entity after catching Doctrine exception

Tags: exception, doctrine, listener, symfony4, flush

I'm trying to create a log system on my website running Symfony 4.
Everytime an exception is thrown, I catch it into a listener, and then **create a Log entity containing the exception values** and also send it to me by email.

But the fact is **when the exception is a Doctrine PDO Exception, the flush seems to crash the app**.
I mean, the flush actually works but all the code **after** is is not executed (mail not sent, redirection not working, ...).

If I comment the flush, everything works fine (except that I don't get my entity persisted of course).

I tried to *clear()* the EntityManagerInterface ; to create a new one ; nothing works.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it. There is not problem doing what I wanted to do. My issue came from a listener I forgot, listening on Doctrine `postFlush` method. When I tried to flush my Log entity, the listener was called, and ran another SQL query that also threw an exception.

As I already passed the `kernel.exception` event, this one wasn't caught, and the server just shew me a 500 page.

Everything works fine now.